# Возможно ли в паскале выводить текст капсом?

Tags: pascalabc.net

Есть программа, которая при вводе слова смешивает его буквы и добавляет недостающие (до 14 символов). Если вводить слово капсом, то на выводе заглавными буквами будут только те, которые мы вводили ранее, а дополнительные будут строчными. Можно ли как то сделать, чтобы все выводимые буквы были заглавными?
Вот код

```
var
  s:string[14];
  c:char;
  i,j:byte;
begin
  randomize;
  write('введите слово:');readln(s);
  for i:=length(s)+1 to 14 do s:=s+chr(random(26)+97);
  for i:=1 to 14 do begin
    j:=random(14)+1;
    c:=s[i];
    s[i]:=s[j];
    s[j]:=c;
   end;
   writeln('результат:',s);
   readln
end.
```

Comment: google: "pascal uppercase"

Comment: @Mike то, что нужно. Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

В **PascalABC.NET** `string.ToUpper / char.ToUpper` возвращает копию строки/символа, переведенную в верхний регистр.

```
'some text'.ToUpper // (string) SOME TEXT
'c'.ToUpper // (char) 'C'
```

Аналогично `string.ToLower / char.ToLower` возвращает копию строки/символа, переведенную в нижний регистр.

```
'SOmE TEXt'.ToLower // (string) some text
'C'.ToLower // (char) 'c'
```